# How display Details in .cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can i display details in `.cshtml` page  while I implementing my DLL File

Controller

```
public ActionResult GetEmpById(int Id)
{
    var x = ObjEmpRepo.GetEmployeesById(Id);
    return View(x);
}
```

View

```
@model Business_Dll.Model.Employee_Model
@foreach (var empDetail in Model)
{   
}
```

Here Business_Dll is My Dll File.
Im Getting Error as

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Business_Dll.Model.Employee_Model' because 'Business_Dll.Model.Employee_Model' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Because you returning a single instance of you model, not a collection.

Comment: but Here i wana to display only single Employee Details..

Comment: Then remove you loop (you cannot loop a single object) - just use `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SomeProperty)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke tq soo much

Comment: why dont you debug yourself in the **.cshtml** .. write something like *@{var item = Model}* and put a debugger on it.... you will see all the stuffs your view model has

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
@model IEnumerable<Business_Dll.Model.Employee_Model>


@foreach (var empDetail in Model)
{   
}
```

Comment: wont this give a model binding error as the page is not binded to IEnumerable<Business_Dll.Model.Employee_Model>

Comment: you can bind the page to an IEnumerable. It will not get an error.

Comment: You need to pass a List of Employee_Model to  View from controller action eg: return View(listOfEmployeeModel)